# Perl HTML::Strip whitelist

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

Is there a way to give a whitelist to the module that it would preserve certain tags?

Now markup as below

```
<div><b>test</b></div>
```

Stripped with this code

```
my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();

open FILE, "<test.markup";
$raw_html=<FILE>;
my $clean_text = $hs->parse( $raw_html );
$hs->eof;
```

Produces output below

```
test
```

However I would like to get with `<b>` tag whitelisted output below.

```
<b>test</b>
```

**EDIT, ONE SOLUTION**

Using [HTML::StripScripts::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~drtech/HTML-StripScripts-Parser-1.03/Parser.pm)

```
my $hss = HTML::StripScripts::Parser->new(
     {
         Context => 'Inline',
         EscapeFiltered  => 0,
         BanAllBut       => [qw(i b u)],
     },
     strict_comment => 0,
     strict_names   => 0,
);

$hss->filter_html("<div><b>test</b></div>");
$cooked = $hss->filtered_document;
$cooked =~ s/<!--filtered-->//g;
print $cooked; // <b>test</b>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading both the Perl wrapper and the underlying XS code, there's no whitelist capability.

It is possible to add, though not 100% trivial - the code already checks tag names for "strip" tags like `<script>` and is only 200LOC.

---

As another approach, RegEx book from O'Reilly has a regular expression recipe that can strip HTML tags (including whitelist capability).

---

If you'd rather not mess with RegEx, try [`HTML::StripScripts::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aStripScripts%3a%3aParser) - it seems it uses whitelists

Comment: Thanks. I used the HTML::StripScripts::Parser solution.